# Highlight text in HTML by int offset (start-end) without knowing actual textNodes

Tags: javascript, highlight

I need to highlight some text in html, given only start and end position (integers, for example from 600th to 712th character).

I am able to do this using [`Range.setStart(startNode, startOffset)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setStart) and [`Range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setEnd), but that works only if I know `startNode` and `endNode`, which are likely to be `textNodes`, inside a shallow element.

Is it possible to highlight text without knowing these nodes ?
If not, what is the optimal solution to determine start and end nodes ? One solution would be to go through DOM and count characters...

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the Help Center to learn how to write a question with the proper format. Edit your question to show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hi @Slobodan , By any chance you have an example where you are using the `Range.setStart` and `Range.setEnd` for highlighting the text using start and end node? I have start and stop values and i need to highlight text based on that in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) to get all the `textNodes` from your main div and then go through their textContent's length to determine where your start and end points should be :

```js
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('main');
// create the treewalker which will accept all textNodes
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(mainDiv,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
// the array containing our textNodes
var textNodeList = [];
while(treeWalker.nextNode()) textNodeList.push(treeWalker.currentNode);

function getRangeFromInt(start, end){
  var indexSizeError = 'IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount';
  if(start>end||start<0){console.warn(indexSizeError); return null;}
  
  var length = 0;
  var startNode, endNode, current=0,
  startPos, endPos;

  while(length<=end){
    // we'been too far ? return
    if(current>=textNodeList.length){console.warn(indexSizeError); return null;}
    // add the length of current node to our total length
    length+=textNodeList[current].textContent.length;
    // start is less than the actual total length ?
    if(start<length && !startNode){
      // then our startNode is here
      startPos = start-(length-textNodeList[current].textContent.length);
      startNode = textNodeList[current];
      }
    // same for the end
    if(end<length && !endNode){
      endPos = end-(length-textNodeList[current].textContent.length);
      endNode = textNodeList[current];
      }

    current++;
    }

  var range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(startNode, startPos);
  range.setEnd(endNode, endPos);

  var selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  return selection;
  }

var log = document.getElementById('log');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  log.innerHTML = getRangeFromInt(
    this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.value,
    this.previousElementSibling.value);
  },false);
```

```css
p{font-size:.7em}
#log{color: rgba(0,0,0,.7); border:1px solid; position: absolute; font-size:.5em;}
```

```html
<input placeholder="start"/><input placeholder="end"/><button>getRange</button>
<div id="main"><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel sodales odio. Nunc a nisi blandit, gravida augue quis, tristique ante. Aliquam in sem at tellus tincidunt ornare. Mauris ut scelerisque sapien. Pellentesque dignissim erat enim, vestibulum molestie diam ultrices eget. Nullam semper leo sit amet ante porttitor, vel tincidunt lorem 
</p>
<p>
Nam pellentesque id nulla at venenatis. Integer arcu nisi, suscipit sit amet here neque ac, hendrerit finibus nisl. Morbi quis volutpat libero. Pellentesque in sapien eu magna finibus tempor. Aliquam posuere ornare dolor, vel maximus felis tincidunt vel. Curabitur ac risus ut augue 
</p>
<p>
Pellentesque sollicitudin risus eu mi sollicitudin maximus eu at turpis. here Nunc iaculis tellus neque, in sollicitudin diam sollicitudin nec. Donec vitae urna nec nibh pharetra pulvinar. Proin eget dolor id quam porta 
</p>
<p>
Suspendisse malesuada, elit a blandit efficitur, mi sem molestie orci, at vulputate here erat diam quis mi. Mauris feugiat faucibus semper. Nulla tempor et velit quis interdum. Proin tincidunt lacus ut lacus auctor scelerisque. Aliquam pharetra risus laoreet nulla commodo, at eleifend ipsum dapibus. Pellentesque dignissim congue diam, a fermentum diam 
</p></div>
<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: This is the solution I went with. To be honest I havent heard about the tree walker so I implemented this procedure of getting a subtree by myself. I will examine this and refactor my code to use tree walker. Thanks!